# embedSwf center and resize

Tags: resize, flash, embed, center

i looked on every piece of help regarding my issue n still no results. I want to have this swf centered on the webpage and to resize so the whole swf file is in view no matter the screen size and i want it to be in a fixed position like a bg. I have try to implement every thing ive seen on this website with very little to no success. this is the base of what i have so far. If you require anything else pls let me know.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
             <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
             <title>CountdownFX</title>

      </head>
    <body style="background-color:black; background-attachment: fixed;">

    <div id="DivCountdownFX" stye="position:absolute;">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var flashvars = {};
            var params = {};
            params.base = "";
            params.scale = "noscale";
            params.salign = "tl";
            params.wmode = "transparent";
            params.allowFullScreen = "true";
            params.allowScriptAccess = "always";
            swfobject.embedSWF("CountdownFX.swf", "DivCountdownFX", "1268", "1269", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params);
        </script>
            </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: what's the html when you publish it from flash? i can help you modify that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, remove `position:absolute` from the inline style for `#DivCountdownFX`. Then, create the following class:

```
#DivCountdownFX {
    margin:auto;
    // If the div is fixed-width, use the following line:
    width:[the width of your div];

    // If your div is fluid width or part of a responsive layout, don't use the above, but rather,
    text-align:center;
}
```